# Bash/Shell Echo Globbing Pattern

Tags: bash, shell, unix

new to Unix shell commands. I need to echo files in current directory who's names DO NOT start with 'cs'.

Comment: Or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
shopt -s extglob # Enable extended globbing
echo !(cs*)
```

Comment: @sehe: ksh and zsh support it in their own way. Not a clue about csh.

Comment: I am marking yours correct as it gave me the push in the right direction. 
Easier way for my sake was simply echo [!cs]*

Comment: Except that's incorrect, since it will echo files that don't start with either "c" or "s".

Comment: @Ignacio: For tcsh: `echo ^*.cs` (plain csh doesn't support this).

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -regex ".*/cs.*"
```

Comment: Wouldn't `ls | grep -v '\.cs$'` be simpler?

Comment: It probably would, but it could match other bits if `-l` is passed to `ls`.

Comment: `-l` shouldn't be a problem, since it's anchored with `$`.  `-F` would be.